# How to bypass AWS Lambda size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have a lambda with **many dependencies**. Due to which the overall size of lambda package is around **1GB**.
Is there any way I can deploy by bulky lambda package?

Answer (score 4):

You can use container image for lambda

[Lambda can now support images up to 10 GB.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to group your dependencies into lambda layers, although not ideal because they are limited.

> You can include up to five layers per function, which count towards the unzipped deployment package size limit of 250 MB.

[Working with Lambda layers and extensions in container images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20include%20up%20to%20five%20layers%20per%20function%2C%20which%20count%20towards%20the%20unzipped%20deployment%20package%20size%20limit%20of%20250%20MB.%20Layers%20are%20automatically%20set%20as%20private%2C%20but%20they%20can%20be%20shared%20with%20other%20AWS%20accounts%2C%20or%20shared%20publicly.)